# How to handle exception C#?

Tags: string, exception, null, double

I am trying to convert a string to a NULL so it can be handled by MySQL. However, I get 'Cannot convert string to double'. 
I want to throw an exception so I can handle any string that is inputted, can this be done??

```
try
{
    Double dDate = Convert.ToDouble(cellData);
    DateTime dt = DateTime.FromOADate(dDate);
    cellString = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    if (cellString.Length == 0)
        cellString = "NULL";
    else
        cellString = "'" + MySqlHelper.EscapeString(cellString) +         "'";

   // throw new EncoderFallbackException("Testing 123");
}
catch (InvalidCastException)
{
    cellString = "NULL";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    oWorkbook.Close();
    m_iSystemOk = false;
    return bResult;
}
```

**UPDATE Following OP comment to an answer**

This is how `cellData` is defined:

```
var cellData = oWorksheet.Cells[row, col].Value2;
string cellString = "";

if (cellData != null)
{
    if (col == 6 || col == 9 || col == 10)
    {
        try (code continues as above statement)
```

Comment: `cellData` is a `Range` object, but you are treating it as if it is a `string`

Answer (score 0):

This line is likely causing the issue for you, due to the fact that whatever is in `cellData` is not being successfully converted to a `double`:

```
Double dDate = Convert.ToDouble(cellData);
```

Instead of `Convert.ToDouble`, try instead to use `double.TryParse`:

```
if (double.TryParse(cellData, out double dDate))
{
    ... The rest of your code
}
else
{
    // cellData is NOT a double. Do something here to handle it
}
```

The reason to change this is because `TryParse` returns a boolean indicating whether it has been successful or not **rather than throwing an exception**.

This gives you a graceful way to handle the conversion failure.

Comment: That gives me the following error:
The best overloaded method match for 'double.tryparse(string, out double)' has some invalid argumetns

Comment: Is InvalidCastException the correct exception for me to handle?

Comment: What is `cellData`? That would give me the impression that it is not a string

Comment: its a variable:
var cellData = oWorksheet.Cells[row, col].Value2;
                        string cellString = "";
                        if (cellData != null)
                        {
                            if (col == 6 || col == 9 || col == 10)
                            {
                                try

Comment: try being the first try in the opening question

Comment: @Joe What are you expecting to do here?  `cellData` is a **Range** object.  How are you expecting to use that as a `string`?

Comment: if one of the 'date' columns above has a string in it, I want to handle that exception and convert it to Null which is already dealt with in the code and accepted by MySQL. Apologies my explanations aren't great, I'm still quite new :|

Comment: I had the wrong exception. Changed to catch (FormatException) and its working

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong exception. Changed to catch (FormatException) and its working